# How to find height of the inner element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

The html structure is:

```
<table class='cls_Name'>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>some operation/text</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To get the height of the table I am doing as below:

```
$('.cls_Name').height();
```

It returns proper value.

Now I want the height of div:

```
$('.cls_Name').children('td:nth-child(2)').children('div').height();
```

But it is returning Null or sometimes also gives error.

Please let me know if anyone has the idea about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
$('.cls_Name td:eq(1)').find('div').height();
```

Comment: That `<td>` is the second `<td>` in the entire `<table>`, but the first in the `<tr>` (its parent) - are you sure `:nth-child(2)` is going to select it? As [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hqb4/) shows, it's not the correct selector for that element.

Comment: true it was just a small rewrite, should have tested it, changed

Comment: I am also not sure. In one of the code I did it and it was in SharePoint. So I didnot get the html structure. I just applied and it worked. Dont know it was in the single tr or different tr .... But the solution you provided is worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `<td>` elements are descendants, but *not* children, of the `<table>` element. The `.children()` function only goes down a single level in the DOM - so, in this case, to the level of the `<tr>` elements. Try the following instead:

```
$('.cls_Name').find('td:eq(1)').children('div').height();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is done.
But I have a doubt about td for its descendent.
When I use td like below:
$(this).children("td:nth-child(4)").css("font-size", "10px");  
$(this).children('td:nth-child(6)').children("div").css('text-align', 'center');
It worked .... but when use the same for height(), it doesnot?

Comment: @HarishHatnapure Difficult to know what the issue is without seeing the full HTML the code is being executed on.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.children('td:nth-child(2)')` does not exists try `.children('td:nth-child(1)')` instead.

**Tested Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        console.log($('.cls_Name').find('td:nth-child(1)').find('div').height());
    });

</script>
<table class='cls_Name'>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>some operation/text</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

that shown me `20` in `console.log()`;

Answer (score 0):

Better you can specify class name for div element and try this:

```
<table class='cls_Name'>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="operation">some operation/text</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$('.operation').height()
```

Comment: No I coluldnt apply class as I have to generate hight of div dynamically and also without its class name.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the better i guess :

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var sa = $('.cls_Name').find('div').height();
    alert(sa);


 });
```